# IBM Worklight - jQuery not recognizing any element on html page

Tags: jquery, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have been trying to call a function on button click in HTML page but somehow the function defined in .js file is being called but i am unable to perform work on any element defined in HTML page. None of my element is being accessed by jQuery. I have tried reading many things and trying out different combinations but nothing seems to work.

I created a new IBM Worklight project named "Hello". So when i add the above HTML content in `Hello.html` and the above JS code in `Hello.js`, the code works perfectly fine. But when I create a new `UI.html` and `control.js` in the same project and the respective contents as stated above the code is not working...

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="AppBody">
        <div id="header">
             <h1>UI Controls</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="button" id='SimpleDialogStartButton' value="SimpleDialog" onclick="w()" />
            <input type="button" id='BusyIndicatorStartButton' value="BusyIndicator for 5 seconds" onclick="w()" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/control.js"></script>
</body>
```

and here is my `control.js`:

```
    var busyIndicator = null;

    function w() {
       // alert("bvgb");
        busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator({
            text: "LOADING..."
        }, {
            color: "RED"
        });
        $('#SimpleDialogStartButton').click(simpleDialogDemo);
        $('#BusyIndicatorStartButton').click(busyIndicatorDemo);
    }
    function busyIndicatorDemo() {
        alert("fdsddsds");
        busyIndicator.show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            busyIndicator.hide();
        }, 5000);
    }
    function simpleDialogDemo() {
        var dialogTitle = "CommonControls";
        var dialogText = "This is simple dialog text";
        WL.SimpleDialog.show(dialogTitle, dialogText, [{
            text: 'I am button 1',
            handler: simpleDialogButton1Click
        }, {
            text: 'I am button 2',
            handler: simpleDialogButton2Click
        }    
function simpleDialogButton1Click() {
alert("simpleDialogButton1 Clicked");

}

function simpleDialogButton2Click() {
alert("simpleDialogButton2 Clicked");
}
```

Even if i try adding this line in function w() above

```
 $("#p1").css("border","3px solid red");
```

and

```
 <p id='p1'>kjbdsds</p>
```

In my HTML code, still nothing works.

Comment: Are these methods called inside document.ready??

Comment: No but if i uncomment alert("") inside the w() function alert is called but the rest code doesnt seem to work

Comment: You should call these inside document.ready because only then dom elements are surely present and then you can access them. Are you getting any console errors?Where are you calling w()?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you created a jsFiddle

Comment: I am calling w() on button click SimpleDialogStartButton and BusyIndicatorStart Button and the $document.ready is also not working . The above code is working perfectly fine when i am using this code with the main html and js file of the ibm worklight project named Hello i.e when i am writing the content in Hello.html nd hello.js this is working fin but if i am creating a new Html and js file the code doesnt works

Comment: @user3079154, is the below answer of help? is this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you need to stop for a moment from everything you are doing, and then go through the **training modules** IBM Worklight provides to you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

By doing so you will then understand that **Worklight is a single page application**. You cannot simply include more HTML files in your application and expect them to work.

In addition, as you've mentioned jQuery (v1.9.1) is bundled with Worklight. Anything you'd, properly, do in your main HTML and JS files (the ones auto-generated when you create a new project and application in Worklight Studio), will work.

---

When you create a *new* HTML file and apply to it these changes you've mentioned in the question - it will not work because not jQuery nor the Worklight framework files are being referenced in it, so it is simply some lonely HTML file, not connected to anything.

If you will load, for example, this new HTML file from the main HTML file of the application, you will **lose the Worklight context and the app will stop working**.

You cannot have more than 1 HTML file in your Worklight application.

However! If what you are looking to do is to create an application with *multiple pages*, then I again suggest to take a look at the documentation, as there is a dedicated training module for this as well (see below).

Training modules: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

- [Building a multi-page application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf)
- [Working with UI frameworks](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf)

Comment: +1 from me for stating the truth `stop everything you are doing, and then you need to study the training modules`

Comment: Did you just delete the other answer that was here, including all the comments under it? That was bad form. Just because that answer/comments were wrong, doesn't mean you can just delete them willy-nilly. I would vote down your answer if I had enough reputation.

Comment: @trysis, Delete another person's answer? I am not a moderator in this website so I cannot do this, but please go ahead and downvote if you feel like it. o_O

Comment: Ok thank you i will get back after going thru this although i am following this site only but maybe i have skipped some important point

Comment: Even I have also not deleted anybody's answer

Comment: Huh, that's weird. There was another answer here, but now it's gone. I assumed someone deleted it, because how else would it have gone away? But if you guys are saying you didn't... Huh.

Comment: Perhaps the person who wrote that answer saw mine and decided to remove his/hers. I've done this to my own answers in the past as well.

Comment: Maybe. Well either way I apologize for blaming you. I'm still giving the side-eye to that answer-giver because he/she removed comments as well, but that is the answer-giver's prerogative, not the commenters'.